# Using TTL thermal Printer USB

Tags: printing, adafruit

I was following these [installation instruction](https://learn.adafruit.com/networked-thermal-printer-using-cups-and-raspberry-pi/connect-and-configure-printer) about configuring a TTL Thremal printer in USB.

Thus when I try : `echo -e This is a test.\\n\\n\\n > /dev/ttyUSB0` it gives me a `bash: no permission`. I tried using sudo mode : it gaves me the same result

The printer seems to work : it has its LED light blinking.

Any idea why ?

Thanks in advance

[edit]

I tried : `sudo ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` and got: cannot access to '/dev/ttyUSB0' : no file or directory

And `echo -e 'this is a test\n\n | sudo tee /dev/ttyUSB0` print the this is a test on the terminal

[edit 2]

I continued the installation instruction and could print using

`echo "Test \n" | lp`

and using the cups cmd on OSX

`lpstat -p`

The terminal could print the name of the printer

Thus I could embed the cmd in a python script:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('echo "printing some text \n" | lp -d "ZJ_58___Thermal_Printer___raspberrypi"', shell=True)
                
subprocess.run(["lp", "-d", "ZJ_58___Thermal_Printer___raspberrypi", f"{path_to_img}", "-o", "Portrait"])
```

Comment: Look up Linux permissions.  Check the permissions required to access /dev/ttyUSB0 and contrast against your user's permissions.  Nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: I tried `sudo chmod a+rwx dev/`, it gives the same result

Comment: Can you edit you question with the output of `sudo ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` and what happens with `echo -e This is a test.\\n\\n\\n | sudo tee /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: @Andrew I did the edit : note that on `libusb -t` it shows as `Port 2: Dev 26, If 0, Class=Printer, Driver=usblp, 12M`

Comment: Can I confirm - you can print to the device but not list the security settings?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`echo -e "This is a test.\\n\\n\\n" > /dev/usb/lp0`

instead of

`echo -e "This is a test.\\n\\n\\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0`

This took hours for me to figure out, full credit to this guide: https://www.theamplituhedron.com/articles/How-to-use-a-tiny-thermal-printer-with-Raspberry-Pi/